# How to copy one array's values to another, where the indices of the second array equal the values of the first?

Tags: matlab

How can I write the following in one matlab line, without using `for`?

```
for i=1:5
    a(a==i) = b(i);
end
```

Comment: Are `b` and `i` the same size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `a` consist exclusively of values in [1:5]?   Your question title says you want to use the values of `a` as indices of `b`.  You can just do that directly:

```
a = b(a);
```

Comment: `a` consists exclusively of values in [1:5] but maybe not all of them. i.e `a` might be `[2 3 1 1 5]` , and `b=[0 0 10 10 10]`. Result should be: `[0 10 0 0 10]`

Comment: Yup, that works.  It doesn't have to contain all of them.  Your test case works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is kinda messy, but it works,

```
a = randi(9,[5 5]);
i = 1 : 5;
b = [5 7 8 9 2];
[c,loc] = ismember(a,i);
loc = reshape(loc,1,[]);
loc(loc>0) = b(loc(loc>0));
loc = reshape(loc,size(c));
 a.* ~c +  loc .* c
```

for example,

```
aold =

 7     2     8     1     8
 9     1     9     3     3
 4     9     1     1     2
 2     8     8     5     1
 1     7     7     5     4


anew =

 7     7     8     5     8
 9     5     9     8     8
 9     9     5     5     7
 7     8     8     2     5
 5     7     7     2     9
```

and `b = [5 7 8 9 2];`.